# PHP not inserting into SQL columns

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm using Ajax to collect the data such as the winningReddit, the LosingReddit, and the win and lose photos. The PHP script (below) is then supposed to send that to the MySQL tables. The "win" and "lose" columns should increase by 1 each time.

For some reason this script is not saving to the database though. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

```
<?php
if(isset ($_POST['action'])) {

include( 'connection.php');

$winnerLink = $_POST['winnerReddit'];
$loserLink = $_POST['losingReddit'];
$win = $_POST['win'];
$lose = $_POST['lose'];


mysql_query("UPDATE $winnerLink SET win = win + 1 WHERE imagelink = '$win'");
mysql_query("UPDATE $loserLink SET lose = lose + 1 WHERE imagelink = '$lose'");

}

?>
```

Here's the Ajax code I'm using:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://website.com/vote.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'save',
            win: chosenURL,
            lose: chosenURL,
            winnerReddit: $(this).attr('id'),
            losingReddit: $(this).siblings('div').attr('id')
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('sent');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('nope')
        }
    });
})
})
```

Comment: Try outputting the SQL to make sure it looks like you think it does - maybe save them to a log file?

Comment: you should put quotes around your $win and $lose in the SQL, also you should really use a prepared statement to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: You probably need quotes around the value: `"WHERE imagelink = '$win'"`

Comment: Check for errors with  `mysql_error()`

Comment: P.S. You shouldn't use `$_POST` values directly in a query like that.  What if I posted `win="''; DROP TABLE users; -- "`?

Comment: data sanitisation lesson in a funny comic strip: http://xkcd.com/327/ :D

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $winnerLink SET win = win + 1 WHERE imagelink = $win");
mysql_query("UPDATE $loserLink SET lose = lose + 1 WHERE imagelink = $lose");
```

With this prepared statement:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare("UPDATE ? SET win = win + 1 WHERE imagelink = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['winnerReddit'], $_POST['win']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$stmt = mysqli_prepare("UPDATE ? SET lose = lose + 1 WHERE imagelink = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['losingReddit'], $_POST['lose']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

You will also need make sure you have [connected to a database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php).

Comment: I wouldn't use `$winnerLink` in the query without escaping it first.

Comment: what is the output of this line: echo "(" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error ?

Comment: It's been too long since I've work with PHP.. one sec, updating answer

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` instead of `$stmt->bind_param`?

Comment: Ok this is what I'm getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/jacksong/public_html/website.com/vote.php on line 27

Comment: I'm trying to keep track of what you are seeing, what is on line 27?

Comment: $stmt->bindParam(':table', $_POST['losingReddit'] );

Comment: Ah, I updated my answer (I was mixing PDO and MySQLi as Rocket pointed out)

Comment: Do I need to modify "imagelink =?"? I'm not longer getting any errors but it still refuses to submit to my database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15394/discussion-between-jason-sperske-and-colby-aley)